# A parametrically defined circle in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

that's a shame for me, but I have a problem with provement of the shape of curve in the complex plane analytically.
The equation given is:
$$F[t] =(1-\frac{A/B}{1+2iA(t/t_{r}-1)})$$
Where $A$, $B$ and $t_{r}$ are constants and $t$ is variable. In the complex plane, namely, $(Re[F[t]], Im[F[t]])$ I get pure circle, which is well fitted. I tried to find complex parametrisation like $$z[t] = x_{0}+iy_{0}+Rcos(t)+iRsin(t)=z_{0}+Re^{it}$$ but it didn't work well because $$z[t] = 1 - \frac{A}{B}\frac{1}{1+4A^{2}(\frac{t}{t_{r}}-1)^{2}}\sqrt{1+4A^{2}(\frac{t}{t_{r}}-1)^{2}}e^{-i arctg[2A(\frac{t}{t_{r}}-1)]}$$
Should I somehow try to use such a parametrisation $$A(x^{2}+y^{2})+Bx+Cy+D=0$$ or it would be wrong? Could you give me some tips how to prove the circle shape and find its center and radius? I appreciate any help.